# django-south migration order

Tags: django, django-south, database-migration

South run migrations per app not in order migrations where created. This may cause some problem with dependencies between migrations. Sometimes it's needed to add **depends_on** attribute to migration class.

Is it possible to run south-migration in order they were created? And also, anyone know reason why south is doing it this way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

South has no idea in what order you created migrations between multiple apps. It could look at the file system metadata, but that would break horribly with 3rd party apps installed through a package manager, or when you deploy your app.

The `depends_on` and `needed_by` attributes where made exactly for this use case, so use them for that. See also http://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html.